# Append elements to div but before another element inside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm appending content from an ajax call into an element, but I have a button in that element that I'd like to always stay at the bottom underneath all the appended elements. But right now the appended elements are going after the button.

HTML

```
 <div id="pagecontent" class="wrapper">
  <!-- WANT APPENDED ELEMENTS TO APPEND HERE -->
     <div class="btnholder">
      <a id="continue" class="continue" href="javascript:;">get more</a>
     </div><!-- WANT TO KEEP AT BOTTOM HERE-->
 </div>
```

JQUERY

```
success: function(data){
    $("#pagecontent").append(data);
 },
```

The (data) coming in is basically a simple div that continually appends new divs.

```
 <div class="floatleft"></div>
```

Important to note that I don't think prepend() works properly because I have a button that fetches records from a database and is supposed to append each record under the other. With prepend I think it brings the records on top of the other as opposed to below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

```js
var  i = 1
function prependData(){
     
    $( ".btnholder" ).before("<div class='floatleft'>someText"+i+"</div>");
  i++;
 };
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-8WqyJLuWKRBVhxXIL1jBDD7SDxU936oZkCnxQbWwJVw="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="pagecontent" class="wrapper">
  <!-- WANT APPENDED ELEMENTS TO APPEND HERE -->
     <div class="btnholder">
      <a id="continue" class="continue" href="javascript:;">get more</a>
     </div><!-- WANT TO KEEP AT BOTTOM HERE-->
 </div>
<button onClick="prependData()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this
you have to create a new div and then use .append()

HTML :

```
<div id="pagecontent" class="wrapper">
<!--CREATE NEW DIV ELEMENT-->
    <div id="forappend"></div>
    <!--WANT APPENDED ELEMENT TO APPEND HERE-->
    <div class="btnholder">
        <a id="continue" class="continue" href="javascript:;">get more</a>
    </div>
    <!-- WANT TO KEEP AT BOTTOM HERE-->
```

JQUERY :

```
success: function(data){
$("div #forappend").append(data);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `insertBefore()`. Please go through the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

```
$( "<div class="floatleft"></div>" ).insertBefore( ".btnholder" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the

> $.prepend()

function.

```js
function prependData(){
    $("#pagecontent").prepend("<div class='floatleft'>someText</div>");
 };
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-8WqyJLuWKRBVhxXIL1jBDD7SDxU936oZkCnxQbWwJVw="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="pagecontent" class="wrapper">
  <!-- WANT APPENDED ELEMENTS TO APPEND HERE -->
     <div class="btnholder">
      <a id="continue" class="continue" onClick="prependData()" href="javascript:;">get more</a>
     </div><!-- WANT TO KEEP AT BOTTOM HERE-->
 </div>
```

Comment: the problem with prepend is that it makes the elements go backwards. I have a button you click more and it fetches more records from the database. With prepend it stacks the elements backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$( ".btnholder" ).before( "<div class="floatleft"></div>" );
```